# Count(*) with 0 for boolean field

Tags: sql, mysql, count

Let's say I have a boolean field in a database table and I want to get a tally of how many are 1 and how many are 0.  Currently I am doing:

```
SELECT  'yes' AS result, COUNT( * ) AS num
FROM  `table` 
WHERE field = 1

UNION 

SELECT  'no' AS result, COUNT( * ) AS num
FROM  `table` 
WHERE field =  0;
```

Is there an easier way to get the result so that even if there are no false values I will still get:

```
----------
|yes | 3 |
|no  | 0 |
----------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because there aren't any existing values for false, if you want to see a summary value for it - you need to LEFT JOIN to a table or derived table/inline view that does.  Assuming there's no TYPE_CODES table to lookup the values, use:

```
   SELECT x.desc_value AS result,
               COALESCE(COUNT(t.field), 0) AS num
     FROM (SELECT 1 AS value, 'yes' AS desc_value
                UNION ALL
                SELECT 2, 'no') x
LEFT JOIN TABLE t ON t.field = x.value
   GROUP BY x.desc_value
```

Comment: I'm trying this but getting 1 if the result should be 0 because the LEFT JOIN is returning 1 row filled with NULLs on the right side.

Comment: @Matt McCormick: Updated, try now

Answer (score 4):

One way would be to outer join onto a lookup table. So, create a lookup table that maps field values to names:

```
create table field_lookup (
    field int,
    description varchar(3)
)
```

and populate it

```
insert into field_lookup values (0, 'no')
insert into field_lookup values (1, 'yes')
```

now the next bit depends on your SQL vendor, the following has some Sybase (or SQL Server) specific bits (the outer join syntax and isnull to convert nulls to zero):

```
select description, isnull(num,0)
from (select field, count(*) num from `table` group by field) d, field_lookup  fl
where d.field =* fl.field
```

Comment: There's a *lot* of not just TSQL in there, but it's **incredibly** *old* TSQL.  That will definitely not run on MySQL, and the join to a lookup table is over complicated - no need for a derived table/inline view, just join to the lookup table if you want the `description` value...

Answer (score 3):

you are on the right track, but the first answer will not be correct. Here is a solution that will give you Yes and No even if there is no "No" in the table:

```
SELECT 'Yes', (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Tablename WHERE Field <> 0)
UNION ALL
SELECT 'No', (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tablename WHERE Field = 0)
```

Be aware that I've checked Yes as <> 0 because some front end systems that uses SQL Server as backend server, uses -1 and 1 as yes.

Regards
Arild

Comment: Kind of like true, false, file_not_found? :)

Answer (score 2):

This will result in two columns:

```
SELECT SUM(field) AS yes, COUNT(*) - SUM(field) AS no FROM table
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) count, field FROM table GROUP BY field;
```

Not exactly same output format, but it's the same *data* you get back.

If one of them has none, you won't get that rows back, but that should be easy enough to check for in your code.

Comment: will not work when there are no false values (as OP requested), but i'd do it the same way